# Desenvolvimento Android studio

Tags: android

Qual função utilizo para  obter uma animação de créditos , onde as letras irão fluir diante da tela , no caso de baixo para cima ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J Mateus.
Vou-te explicar rapidamente a lógica de como eu fazia.
Eu criava um timer que de 50 em 50 ou 150 em 150, que ia desenhar o texto/créditos diminuindo a posição.

O código seria alguma como isto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int X,Y;

  TimerTask mudarCreditos= new TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay();
  Timer tempo = new Timer();

  tempo.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew,tempo para começar pode ser 0,tempo para repetir 150);      
  }
// este metodo é o que vai acontecer de 150 em 150 ms
  public void run() {
  //diminuir 20px de cada vez pode ser o Y ou ambos
  //X-=20;
  Y-=20; 
  TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
  txtView.setX(X);
  txtView.setY(Y);
  //Invalidate serve para redesenhar
  invalidate();
   }
```

A maneira como vai fazer **invalidate e os objetos vão depender** se vais utilizar um layout em XML ou em um layout programável.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Mas e o texto , deverei coloca-lo dentro de uma TextView mesmo , para chamá-lo ?

Comment: Sim pode colocá-lo dentro de uma TextView, no código já atualizei ;)

Comment: A resposta foi essencial , agradeço!.

Comment: Espero que tenha sido útil para ajudar-te a resolver esse problema. Mas um conselho próximas vezes que comentares aqui no fórum lembra-te daquelas dicas que dei e lembra-te de postares sempre uma imagem com código para nos ajudares a perceber melhor. Tenta também ser o mais simples e claro possível

Comment: Os meus próximos comentários serão mais simples e claros , estou utilizando o stack overflow a pouco tempo,peço desculpa pelos erros.

Comment: Não há problema ;)

Comment: Em relação a imagemView ,como posso obter a ação de clicar nela e efetuar um pulo?

Comment: Poes isto nas definições da ImageView `android:clickable="true"` e depois o código `imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   //@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.v(TAG, " click");         
   }        
});`

Comment: Compreendi à ação de (clicar) na imagemView , mas  e o pulo da imagem , como posso  obter essa ação ao clicar?

Comment: Pulo como assim?

Comment: Quando clicar na ImageView ela ir para cima e depois voltasse  para baixo ,estou desenvolvendo um game e precisaria dessa função para continuar.

Comment: Eu já te disse como Mateus, fazes aquilo `.setY` e depois passado um tempo diminuis outra vez